# dataTable.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, datatable

i am using `dataTable` in my UI, when i am assigning values to it the Following error is occurring

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
at W (dataTable.js:65)
at ya (dataTable.js:70)
at e (dataTable.js:91)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (dataTable.js:93)
at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:368)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:157)
at jQuery.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (dataTable.js:82)
at Object.success (isevaEnquirySearch.html:122)
at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.js:3435)
```

and my code looks like this

```
 $("#tblData").dataTable().fnDestroy();
            $('#tblData').dataTable({
                data : response,

                                    columns : [

                                               {    'data'  :   ' date' },
                                                {   'data'  :    ' source1' },
                                                {   'data'  :     'source2  '},
                                                {   'data'  :     'callon'  },
                                                {   'data'  :     'callby'  },
                                                {   'data'  :     'name'    },
                                                {   'data'  :     'sbiaccountsmsSentCheck'  },
                                                {   'data'  :     'sbiaccountsmsSentDate'   },
                                                {   'data'  :     'number1' },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formFilledUpCheck'   },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formFilledUpDate'    },
                                                {   'data'  :     'number2' },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formCouriredCheck'   },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formCouriredDate'    },
                                                {   'data'  :     'email1'  },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formReciCheck'   },
                                                {   'data'  :     'formReciDate'    },
                                                {   'data'  :     'email2'  },
                                                {   'data'  :     'payreciCheck'    },
                                                {   'data'  :     'payreciDate' },
                                                {   'data'  :     'pan' },
                                                {   'data'  :     'remarks' 
    },


                                               ],


                                    }) ;
```

if i remove  `$("#tblData").dataTable().fnDestroy();` this line from the code
its getting executed but the sorting and search fields are not working and the following exceptions is coming

```
DataTables warning: table id=tblData - Requested unknown parameter ' date' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

i am not able to trace it can any one help me

Comment: Have a look at this demo hope this will help : https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: i have edited my question will you check it once